# Using JButton to access Another Frame in another class

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

Hi everyone I'm new to java. I'm trying to redirect my "Next" JButton to another frame (DriversLicenseApplicant) in another class. The problem is when I click "Next" button it kept on opening the frame which my program is currently executing which is MainInfo.  Can you help me with my code? thank you all. :)

```
    final JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    btnNext.setBounds(824, 623, 89, 51);
    contentPane.add(btnNext);
        btnNext.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (btnNext.isSelected()) {
            DriversLicenseApplicant frame = new DriversLicenseApplicant();
            MainInfo objMain = new MainInfo();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                        objMain.setVisible(false);



        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

## What is happening

The key lines are here

```
1  DriversLicenseApplicant frame = new DriversLicenseApplicant();
2  MainInfo objMain = new MainInfo();
3  frame.setVisible(true);
4  objMain.setVisible(false);
```

Before this block, you have one frame `this`. (In Java, you refer to the object you're in as [`this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html8).) `this` is open.

At line 1, you create a new frame `frame`, bringing your total frames to two. `frame` is hidden.

At line 2, you create a third frame `objMain`. It is in the same class as `this` but it's a different instance. (Explanations of the difference between Class and Instance can be found [on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486212/830988) and [on Oracle's website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)). `objMain` is hidden, but `this` is open.

At line 3, you open `frame`. Now both `this` and `frame` are open, while `objMain` is hidden. `this` keeps focus because of [Java's focus rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

At line 4, you hide `objMain`. This has no effect because `objMain` was never open in the first place. You still have 3 frames, both `this` and `frame` are open, and `this` still has focus.

## How to fix it

Replacing those lines with

```
DriversLicenseApplicant frame = new DriversLicenseApplicant();
frame.setVisible(true);
this.setVisible(false);
```

will open the new frame and hide to current one.

But I think there might be an underlying design issue. Each program should normally have only one frame. You might want to look into using a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) for the second window. You could also keep them both in the same frame and switch between them using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). Also change your classes to extend [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), so you can put them in the content pane of your windows. It adds flexibility, and it's useful for whichever method you choose.

## One more thing

I can't help mentioning the absolute positioning of the JButton. Please use [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). They are your friends.