# EventBus object's methods not working in java

Tags: java, event-bus

I am trying to include EventBus in my application.
I followed http://tomaszdziurko.pl/2012/01/google-guava-eventbus-easy-elegant-publisher-subscriber-cases/ link.

I am getting compile errors:
[image]

I've added the guava-16.0.1.jar to the project.
But the register fucntion isn't working.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Do not post screen captures, post the compiler error message.

Comment: Code need to go into code blocks. This isn't `bash`. You can't just stick code anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call methods on members from the class, which is not possible. Those need to go inside a method (like a constructor or initializer).

Example code:

```
public class EventBusTest {

  private final EventBus eventBus = new EventBus("test");

  private final MultipleListener multiListener = new MultipleListener();

  public void init() {
    eventBus.register(multiListener);
  }

}
```

Also, this question may be of use to help you understand [Classes vs Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances)