# Sending a Java object through javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets, server

Currently I have a Java servlet that takes in a serialized POJO through the request. It works when I send a request from a Java client to the servlet. My question is: is there a way to make such a request through JavaScript using AJAX passing the Java object directly as opposed to converting it to a JSON first? This is how my server receives the Java object

```
ObjectInputStream inData = new ObjectInputStream (request.getInputStream());
SomeClass mUser = (SomeClass) inData.readObject();
```

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript executing in a web browser?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to send an AJAX POST request in javascript specifically

Comment: I think your only option is JSON.

Answer (score 1):

A Java object is just an [instance of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances) in memory. When you pass data from client to server, it has to be serialized one way or another.

Comment: My POJO implements the serializable interface. I just wanted to be able to send a request through JavaScript AJAX with this POJO attached. Is there an easy way for me to do that? I can't seem to find it anywher eonline

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to convert the representation of the Java class instance into something that JavaScript can parse and handle. Java != JavaScript, the two are different technologies.

There are many libraries/frameworks that can help you with the conversion back and forth though. Rather than object serialization, look at using JAX-RS for your serverside resource, and a mapping library like Jackson to map JSON to Java and back.