# Automatically removing object(s) of a removed object

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, instances

I have three classes I am working with. 1)`Category` 2)`MainCategory` 3)`SubCategory`

1. `Category`: responsible for creating/removing Main Categories
2. `MainCategory`: respnsible for creating/removing Sub Categories (and nesting them under their respective main categories)
3. `SubCategory`: Sets/gets the name of its own instances

The problem that I am having is that when I delete one of my Main Category objects (using .remove) the Sub Categories under it remain and get shifted to the next Main Category.  I really want them to be deleted along in case their (Parent) category is has been removed.  I point to the problem in the comments in my Main Method at the end of this post.  Thank you.

### ## Category (Class) ##

```
public class Category {
private ArrayList<MainCategory> mainCat  = new ArrayList<MainCategory>();
private String name;


public void addMainCat (MainCategory name){
    mainCat.add(name);
}


public ArrayList<MainCategory> returnList() {
    return mainCat;
}



public void removeCat(int location){
    System.out.println("The Main Category " + mainCat.get(location).getName() + " has been deleted.");
    mainCat.remove(location);

}

public void removeCat(MainCategory name){
    mainCat.remove(name);
}
```

}

### ## MainCategory (Class) ##

```
public class MainCategory{
private ArrayList<SubCategory> subCat  = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
private String name;


public void addSubCat(SubCategory name){
    subCat.add(name);
}

public void removeSubCat(SubCategory name){
    subCat.remove(name);
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ArrayList<SubCategory> returnList(){
    return subCat;
}
```

}

### ## SubCategory (Class) ##

```
public class SubCategory{


private String name;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

### ## Main (Method) ##

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Category stats = new Category();

    MainCategory mc1 = new MainCategory();
    MainCategory mc2 = new MainCategory();

    SubCategory sc1 = new SubCategory();
    SubCategory sc2 = new SubCategory();

    stats.addMainCat(mc1);
    stats.addMainCat(mc2);

    mc1.setName("salary");

    mc1.addSubCat(sc1);
    mc1.addSubCat(sc2);

    sc1.setName("mean");
    sc2.setName("median");

    System.out.println(stats.returnList().get(0).getName());
    System.out.println(mc1.returnList().get(0).getName());

    stats.removeCat(mc1); // This one is OK.

    System.out.println(stats.returnList().get(0).getName()); // Returns null, GOOD!
    System.out.println(mc1.returnList().get(0).getName()); // Returns mean (it should return null because mc1 was deleted)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is not doing what you /want/ it to do, but what you /tell/ it to do. And you did not remove the category `mc1`, you removed the category referenced by `mc1` from `stats`.

What that means is that in your code you created instances `mc1` and `stats`:

```
Category stats = new Category();
MainCategory mc1 = new MainCategory();
```

then you've added `mc1` to `stats`:

```
stats.addMainCat(mc1);
```

then you remove `mc1` reference from `stats`:

```
stats.removeCat(mc1); // This one is OK.
```

which does:

```
mainCat.remove(location);
```

actually removing the reference `location` from `mainCat` list.

but as in the `main()` you still have a reference to `mc1`, it is still in your memory, and you can still manipulate it.

So you're not actually having any issue, `mc1` is still the object you instanciated before adding it to `stats`, and will remain until you remove all references to the instance by doing `mc1 = null;`, and then at some point it will totally get destroyed thanks to the garbage collector.

Then, in your last two lines of the `main()`, your comment is wrong:

```
System.out.println(stats.returnList().get(0).getName()); // Returns null, GOOD!
System.out.println(mc1.returnList().get(0).getName()); // Returns mean (it should return null because mc1 was deleted)
```

the first one actually returns `mc2`'s value, which happens to be `null` because you did not assign it a name. And then, the second one returns mean, because it is still the same `mc1` object you're been working with within the `main()` function, whatever you did to `stats`.

> *The problem that I am having is that when I delete one of my Main Category objects (using .remove) the Sub Categories under it remain and get shifted to the next Main Category*

So here you got it wrong. The sub categories does not get shifted to the next category, as long as `mc1` is still being referenced, the subcategories will stay instanced along with the category instance. As soon as you dereference them (with e.g. `mc1 = null`) as you will not be able to look at them, they will disappear from the JVM's memory as well.

---

You should read more about how java works with instances and references to instances, to never wonder about this again!

cf:

- [The difference between Classes, Objects, and Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances)
- https://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/
- http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Java/JavaIntro.html#tth_sEc4.4

as a few resources online to toughen up your knowledge of Java!

- https://www.coursera.org/learn/object-oriented-java

HTH

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to make it as clear as possible.  It would have never occurred to me that it's related to "refrences".  Thanks for posting those links I really appreciate the pointers

Comment: well, as you're learning to program, you have to really understand the memory management model you're interacting with. The more high level the language, the less obvious it will be, but you're still storing things in your machine's memory (as all machine are built on the *Von Neuman* model). So it's always a good idea to learn C and deal more directly with memory (allocation, pointers…) so when doing higher level languages it will always look more obvious!

Comment: I actually took the course you recommended and it was such an eye-opener (thank you!).  I learned about the memory management, referencing, heap...etc  !http://s13.postimg.org/fb9vzslh3/reference.jpg

Comment: I'm happy to have helped you ☺ And if you ever want to give back, share what you've learned with others!

Answer (score 1):

You have a still reference to mc1 so it can`t be deleted. You call an instance which one you created in main class so you deleted only a reference from list not whole object in Category class.

Answer (score 1):

You have only removed the reference of main category from the top list, but main category is still an independent list containing more elements as sub list. you should manually removed them as

```
mc1.returnList().clear();
```