# how should I describe this method that create random objects?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I need to insert some comments on this TwoD method, but I am not sure if this is the correct comment for this method as TwoD is the reference Type:

```
// generate a random integer from 1 to 10
private static int getInt() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}

// generate random object of TwoD reference type
private static TwoD getTwoD() {
    // generate a random integer  from 0 to 2
    int randomInt = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    TwoD twoD;

    switch(randomInt) {
        case  0:
            twoD = new Circle(getInt());
            break;

        case 1:
            twoD = new Rectangle(getInt(), getInt());
            break;

        default:
            twoD = new Triangle(getInt(), getInt(), getInt());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating random objects, you're creating random instances.

Read the following question for further information and then write your comments accordingly.

[The difference between Classes, Objects, and Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances)