# Array of classes implementing an interface to call same method

Tags: java, class, interface

I have 4 classes, all implementing an interface `IntSorter`. All classes have a `sort` method, so for each class I want to call `sort` on an array.

I thought something like this would work:

```
IntSorter[] classes = new IntSorter[] {
Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class, Class4.class
};
for (Class c : classes)
    c.sort(array.clone());
```

But `classes` cannot hold the .class names, I get the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Class1> to IntSorter`

So I tried

```
Class[] classes = new Class[] {
Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class, Class4.class
};
for (Class c : classes)
    c.sort(array.clone());
```

But now c.sort() cannot be called. I tried parsing the class to an IntSorter first, with `(IntSorter) c` but then I get the error `Cannot cast from Class to IntSorter`

How do I fix this?

Comment: If IntSorter is an interface, an array IntSorter[] must be initialized with objects which implement IntSorter.  The first example is closer to what you want.  But, instead of putting the several class objects into IntSorter[], put instances of these classes.

Comment: Something like this: IntSorter[] sorters = new IntSorter[] { new Sorter1(), new Sorter2(), new Sorter3() new Sorter4() };.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create array of classes instead of array of instances of classes implementing `IntSorter`.

Check this question to understand difference between Classes, Objects and Instances: [The difference between Classes, Objects, and Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances)

Your code should look something like this, as far as I can tell with limited information available:

```
IntSorter[] classes = new IntSorter[] {
new Class1(), new Class2(), new Class3(), new Class4()
};
for (IntSorter c : classes)
    c.sort(array.clone());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the first approach, but you want `for (IntSorter c : classes)` - and you need to put instances in your array (not the classes). Something like,

```
IntSorter[] classes = new IntSorter[] {
    new Class1(), new Class2(), new Class3(), new Class4()
};
for (IntSorter c : classes) {
    c.sort(array.clone());
}
```